# How to Reattach Cable End for Road Drop Bar Brake Lever

Tags: road-bike, brakes, cable, brake-levers

I was installing new brakes and I pulled too hard on the lever and the cable end disconnected from the brake lever. I'm having trouble reattaching it because it can only be pulled out so far due to the cable housing and it's such a small space. Is there a specific tool i need to use because this happened to me once before and the guy at the bike shop fixed it without removing the housing. I don't want to keep going back to a bike shop every time this happens so I need to know how to do it on my own if I am out on a ride.

Comment: Brakes that brake when you pull too hard are probably due for replacement.

Comment: Do you mean the cable stop in the lever or the cable end cast onto the end of the cable?

Comment: If it came out because you pulled too hard then you have a problem.  But they tend to come out when you're monkeying with them.  You need to loosen the cable clamp on the brake to give yourself some more slack (though often you can just slip a cable housing out of its roost on the frame), then thread the cable back into the lever.  Precisely how you thread it in, though, depends on what kind of lever you have.

Comment: Note that, if the appropriate pieces are aligned properly, there is *usually* a slot in the side of the brake lever housing running from where the cable enters the housing to the point where it attaches to the lever proper.  When the lever is fully pressed, usually there is a hole in the side of the lever that accepts the barrel on the end of the cable.  You get enough slack in the cable, get everything lined up, and then slide the cable into place.

Comment: a picture would help to understand what broke

Comment: This question remains unfinished after 6 months - can you add an answer describing what you did to fix the problem, and how it worked for you?  Its totally okay to add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a guess for anyone who might stumble on this. it sounds like he grabbed the brake lever and pulled tight, perhaps checking for brake pad alignment, spacing, etc. The cable pulled loose from the brake caliper (not lever) and disappeared into the cable housing. If so, grab a zip tie (or a shoe lace) and pull said lever all the way back to the handebar. Secure it to the handlebar by zip tie, shoe lace, whatever. Grab a flashlight and shine it into the innards. You'll see the cable end coming out of the internal guts of the lever. Take a flathead screwdriver or needle nose pliers and push the head slowly back into the lever until it stops. Check the end of the cable housing by the brake caliper and you should see the cut end sticking out. hold on to it and release the brake lever from the handlebar. That should do it.